# Convergence in $L^p$ spaces by subsequences of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I want to show that a sequence of functions in $L^p$ converges $f_n\to f \in L^p$ if every subsequence has a further subsequence that converges to $f\in L^p$.

We are given that every subsequence has a further subsequence that converges to $f\in L^p$. My attempt is to suppose $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ in $L^p$. This means there is some $\varepsilon,\delta,$ and $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $$m(x\vert \|f_{n_k}-f\|_p>\delta)>\varepsilon$$ for all $k$. But we know that there is some $g_k\subseteq f_{n_k}$ such that $g_k\to f$ in $L^p$ since this is given, but this is a contradiction to the line above. Is this correct?

Comment: What is $m(x|\lVert f_{n_k}-f\rVert_p>\delta)$ supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. Actually what you propose works for any topological space with the same reasoning.

Moreover, you can see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370936/every-subnet-of-x-d-d-in-d-has-a-subnet-which-converges-to-a-does-x-d/370951#370951) for more information on nets.

Comment: Is the converse reasoning true as well? i.e. if $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$, does this imply that every subsequence has a further subsequence that converges? I have seen something similar to this regarding the convergence of probability measures.

Comment: @moonknight Yes, that's true; actually it's true for general topological space. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-the?noredirect=1&lq=1).