# Weakly convergent sequence on a strongly compact set is strongly convergent

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, weak-topology

I'm doing Ex 3.7 in Brezis's book of *Functional Analysis*. Could you have a check on my attempt?

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $K \subset E$ be a subset of $E$ that is compact in the strong topology. Let $\left(x_{n}\right)$ be a sequence in $K$ such that $x_{n} \rightharpoonup x$ weakly in $\sigma\left(E, E^{\star}\right)$. Prove that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ strongly.

I posted my proof separately so that I can accept my own answer and thus remove my question from unanswered list. If other people post answers, I will happily accept theirs.

Comment: A compact topological space does not admit a strictly weaker Hausdorff topology. Hence, the topological spaces $(K,$strong) and $(K,$weak) are identical and thus have the same convergent sequences (and nets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lemma:* Let $X$ be a topological space, $x\in E$, and $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ a net in $E$. Then $x_d \to a$ if and only if every subnet of $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ has a further subnet which converges to $a$. [A proof is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/370951/1019043)]

Let $(n_k)_k$ be a subsequence of $\mathbb N$. Then by strong compactness of $K$, there is a subsequence $(n_{k_t})_t$ of $(n_k)_k$ and $a\in K$ such that $x_{n_{k_t}} \to a$ as $t \to \infty$. Because strong convergence implies weak convergence, $x_{n_{k_t}} \rightharpoonup a$ as $t \to \infty$. It follows from $x_{n} \rightharpoonup x$ that $x_{n_{k_t}} \rightharpoonup x$ as $t \to \infty$. Because weak topology is Hausdorff, $a=x$. By our *Lemma*, $x_n \to a$.